# Include carriage-return linefeed in NLog Layout

Tags: vb.net, nlog

Is it possible to include a carriage-return and or linefeed in an NLog layout.  I wish to hold the following format of header information in all my logs:

```
    Application Name: <Application Name> 
    File Version: <Version number>
    Released:  <Release date>
    User: <Windows User>
    etc...

    21|17:07:54|domain\user|Trace|  System.OverflowException: Arithmetic operation
         resulted in an overflow at application.form.Button1_Click(Object sender,
         EventArgs e) in D:\Documents and    
         Settings\user\Mydocuments\workarea\application\application
         project\application.vb:line 47
```

All assistance much appreciated

Regards

Paul J.

Answer (score 10):

NLog has a `${newline}` LayoutRenderer that will add a newline to the output.

If you want the "header" to only appear once in the log file (or once per run), you might want to see this question as well:

[Nlog - Generating Header Section for a log file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4196663/nlog-generating-header-section-for-a-log-file)

This answer also describes adding a header to an NLog log file:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4259447/125439

Comment: +1 Nice and clean; better than trying to modified the layout of the message send to nLog.