# The type or namespace name GlobalDiagnosticsContext does not exist in the namespace Nlog

Tags: c#, logging, nlog

I started exploring features in NLog logging framework. As I was trying with different logging features I have encountered a feature called logging `Header message`. My searching has found following [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4196663/nlog-generating-header-section-for-a-log-file) in stack.

But when pasting following lines

```
 public void AddHeaderToLogFile()
 {
     Logger headerlogger = LogManager.GetLogger("HeaderLogger");

      //Use GlobalDiagnosticContext in 2.0, GDC in pre-2.0
      GlobalDiagnosticContext["releasedate"] = GetReleaseDate();    
      GlobalDiagnosticContext["version"] = GetFileVersion();     
      GlobalDiagnosticContext["someotherproperty"] = GetSomeOtherProperty();

      headerlogger.Info("message doesn't matter since it is not specified in the layout");

      //Log file should now have the header as defined by the HeaderLayout

      //You could remove the global properties now if you are not going to log them in any
      //more messages.
}
```

my VS 2013 is not able to resolve the namespace. My current assembly version of NLog is 2.1.0.0.
Please let me know how to resolve my namespace problem. Am I using correct assembly or should I move to some pre release or older version.

Comment: Have you added the reference?

Comment: As written 'My current assembly version of NLog is 2.1.0.0.' Nuget helped me adding assembly.

Comment: If you are using dotnetfx35 or up then I can definitely advice you to get the latest version of NLog (version 3) via nuget.