# How to format NLog exception output to get a line separator?

Tags: c#, logging, nlog

How to get the below output format using **NLog** error logging; A line separator between each exception log. like;
`2017-06-19 16:53:20|SessionVal| Error message| Exception's Message | StackTrace
_______________________________________________________________________________________ 2017-06-19 16:52:10|SessionVal|Error occured while executing the procedure. 
|Procedure xyz expects varchar(20) @ParameterName.|StackTrace....`

Current NLog configuration;

```xml
<nlog autoReload="true" xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <targets>
    <target name="logfile" xsi:type="File" 
   layout="${date:universalTime=false:format=yyyy-MM-dd HH\:mm\:ss}| 
   ${aspnet- session:Variable=SessionKey} ${message} | 
   ${exception:format=type,message,StackTrace}" 
   fileName="${basedir}/App_Data/Log/ 
   ${date:universalTime=false:format=yyyyMMdd}.log" />
   </targets>
  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="logfile" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

**Update:** @Amy, are you telling like this;
**Update 2:** Thank you @Amy it worked.
    `layout="-------------------------------------------------------------- 
     ${newline}${date:universalTime=false:format=yyyy-MM-dd HH\:mm\:ss}| 
       ${aspnet- session:Variable=SessionKey} ${message} | 
       ${exception:format=type,message,StackTrace}" 
       fileName="${basedir}/App_Data/Log/ 
       ${date:universalTime=false:format=yyyyMMdd}.log"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nlog - Generating Header Section for a log file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4196663/nlog-generating-header-section-for-a-log-file)

Comment: If I understood correctly then according to this thread https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/1713 header is logged only once per file. I need line separator between each exception log entry.

Comment: Why not just embed newline characters in the layout?

Comment: That's an option more of tedious, but was looking if there's any builtin feature to get it without changing in hundreds of different places.

Comment: No, this isn't built-in, and no, you wouldn't have to put it in hundreds of places.  Your layout is right there in your NLog configuration.

Comment: @Amy Would you check the update please.

Comment: yes, with an embedded newline character

Comment: @c-sharp You can also use ${newline} https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Newline-Layout-Renderer

Comment: Please post your own answer as answer, and mark it.

Answer (score -1):

According to the asker of the question this is a solution:

```
layout="-------------------------------------------------------------- 
    ${newline}${date:universalTime=false:format=yyyy-MM-dd HH\:mm\:ss}| 
    ${aspnet- session:Variable=SessionKey} ${message} | 
    ${exception:format=type,message,StackTrace}" 
    fileName="${basedir}/App_Data/Log/ 
    ${date:universalTime=false:format=yyyyMMdd}.log"
```