# NLog write message upon rollover

Tags: c#, nlog

When using NLog with automatic rollover (whether it's size-based or time-based), is it possible to write a single message to each new log file when the log rolls over?

We would like to include product version information in the log files, but adding that information to every log entry makes them longer than they already are.

Ideally, we would like to include the version information at the top of each log file, but to do that requires knowing when the rollover happens so we can write the information at that time, and there does not appear to be a callback that we can use.  Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4196663/nlog-generating-header-section-for-a-log-file

Answer (score 1):

You can configure a `Header` on the File-Target, that is written when new file is created (after archive):

```
<target name="logfile" xsi:type="File" fileName="file.txt" header="${assembly-version}" />
```

See also https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/File-target and https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/AssemblyVersion-Layout-Renderer