# NLog async message order

Tags: thread-safety, nlog

I have an NLog config file with several async targets (`<targets async="true">`). One of the targets is a log file.

I know that [NLOG is thread-safe](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Tutorial#wiki-creating-loggers), but does it guarantee that messages coming from the same thread are written to the log file in the order in which they were produced?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked the same question on the [NLog forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nlog-users/6YRpySlLSek), and got a replay from Kim Christensen, that this is indeed the case:

> Yes logs written from the same thread should be written in the order
> produced.

Thanks Kim!

Answer (score 0):

You can follow [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706119/how-thread-safe-is-nlog) question which has some explaination about thread safety.