# NLog filter by LogLevel as MappedDiagnosticsContext

Tags: c#, nlog

Based on the answer here: [How Thread-Safe is NLog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706119/how-thread-safe-is-nlog) I have created a Logger and added two MappedDiagnosticsContext to NLog:

```
NLog.MappedDiagnosticsContext.Set("Module", string.Format("{0}.{1}", module.ComputerName, module.ModuleType));
NLog.MappedDiagnosticsContext.Set("ModuleCoreLogLevel", string.Format("LogLevel.{0}", module.CoreLogLevel));
```

I can successfully use the "Module" Context in the NLog config (programmatically) to generate the file name the logger should log to:

```
${{when:when=length('${{mdc:Module}}') == 0:inner=UNSPECIFIED}}${{when:when=length('${{mdc:Module}}') > 0:inner=${{mdc:Module}}}}.txt
```

This logs e.g. all messages with a "Module" context of "Test" to a filename called *Module*.txt

I now want to be able to set the LogLevel for the different Modules using this way, and only Log messages which correspond to this LogLevel (or higher)

I am trying to do this through filters, this means, on the LoggingRule I am trying to add a filter:

```
rule92.Filters.Add(new ConditionBasedFilter { Condition = "(level < '${mdc:ModuleCoreLogLevel}')", Action = FilterResult.IgnoreFinal });
```

This however does not seem to filter messages.
If I have for example a message which is emitted using `Logger.Trace()`, and the LogLevel on "ModuleCoreLogLevel" is set to `LogLevel.Debug`, I can still the Message in the resulting LogFile.

Comment: I think I solved this by doing this for each level:
`rule92.Filters.Add(new ConditionBasedFilter { Condition = "(equals('${mdc:ModuleCoreLogLevel}', 'LogLevel.Trace') and level < LogLevel.Trace)", Action = FilterResult.IgnoreFinal });`
Anyone better / faster ideas? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by doing this for each level:

```
rule92.Filters.Add(new ConditionBasedFilter { Condition = "(equals('${mdc:ModuleCoreLogLevel}', 'LogLevel.Trace') and level < LogLevel.Trace)", Action = FilterResult.IgnoreFinal });
```