# NLog - 2 separate log files - How to write to one or the other

Tags: c#, nlog

I want to **explicitly write to 2 different log files**. Based on the method or type of operations.

**How to?**

I have seen the following StackOverFlow post
[Having NLog loggers with different configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6724212/having-nlog-loggers-with-different-configuration)

How do I configure NLog ? What code do I need too, so I can write to 1 file or the other? using code like :`log.Error("My Big Error")`;

The post contains the following

```xml
<targets> 
    <target name="f1" xsi:type="File" fileName="${logger}.txt" />
    <target name="f2" xsi:type="File" fileName="${shortdate}.txt" />
</targets>
```

So, if it's 'general error' I want write to **f1**. If it's file operation error I want to write to **f2**

thx in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the NLog configuration you need to set up some rules to write to the targets (otherwise nothing get logged). In those rules you could add filters and conditions.

### Simple example

For example:

```xml
<rules>
  <logger name="Logger1" writeTo="f1" />
  <logger name="Logger2" writeTo="f2" />
</rules>
```

The `name` attribute is here a filter, so the first rule means: write to f1 if logger name is equals to "Logger1". The rules are processed from top to bottom.

So when calling `LogManager.GetLogger("Logger1").Info("My message")` this will write to target `f1` and `LogManager.GetLogger("Logger2").Info("My message")` will write to target `f2`.

### GetCurrentClassLogger

When using `LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger()`, the logger name is constructed of the current class and namespace name, e.g. "MyNameSpace.MyClass". This means you could adjust the name attribute to `name="MyNameSpace.MyClass"`, or `name="*.MyClass"` for matching.

### Final

You could also write this:

```xml
<rules>
  <logger name="Logger1" writeTo="f1" final="true" />
  <logger name="*" writeTo="f2" />
</rules>
```

This will write events of Logger1 to `f1`, and others to `f2`. You probably need the filter attribute, otherwise also the events of Logger1 will be written to `f2` - and that isn't always what you need.

### Other filter rules

There are many more filter options, e.g. min level, max level, but also more advanced filters (not only on logger name). You could read more about that [here](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-file#rules)