# Generic Logging and Specific Logging (using NLOG), Duplication of Logging

Tags: c#, nlog

I am trying to create 2 loggers (using NLog)

1. First logger logs all the desired item to log in the solution
2. The other one traces specific items (I do it to keep things clean and focused, and only run `trace` here)

Below is the configuration

```xml
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<targets>
  <target name="logfile"
          xsi:type="File"
          layout="${longdate} ${level} ${threadid} ${callsite} ${message}"
          fileName="${basedir}\Logs\GatewayApplicationDebugAndErrorLog.txt"
          archiveNumbering="Rolling"
          maxArchiveFiles="10"
          archiveAboveSize="10000000"/>     
  <target name="J1939Trace"
          xsi:type="File"
          layout="${longdate} ${level} ${threadid} ${callsite} ${message}"
          fileName="${basedir}\Logs\J1939Trace.txt"
          archiveNumbering="Rolling"
          maxArchiveFiles="10"
          archiveAboveSize="10000000"/>
</targets>
<rules>
  <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="logfile" />
  <logger name="J1939Trace" maxlevel="Trace" writeTo="J1939Trace" final="true" />
</rules>
```

and usage is shown below

```
private readonly Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger(); // Generic Logger
private readonly Logger j1939Logger = LogManager.GetLogger("J1939Trace"); // Specific Logger.
```

What I observe is that the specific logger item is also logged in generic log item and I don't want that duplication. Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the intention that the one log is trace, and the other log is above trace?  Could you just change the generic logger to be at debug?

Comment: @derek That is not the intention. The intention id to log every thing except what is  logged in specific logger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will this work?

From: [NLog: How to exclude specific loggers from a specific rule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7995728/nlog-how-to-exclude-specific-loggers-from-a-specific-rule)

Adding final="true" means that no more rules will be executed for the events produced by "SpammyLogger", but it applies only to the specified levels.(see https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Configuration-file#rules)

Make sure to read through all the comments in the answer.

Comment: this works,the order is important! I did not see that.