# Ignore Microsoft.AspNetCore.* messages in NLog logs

Tags: asp.net-core, nlog

I have an ASP.NET Core 2.2 app. I want to use NLog in this app. While I have successfully integrated NLog, there are too many logs being written. Specifically, I see a ton of messages from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.`. I really only want to show messages that comes from my code.

I copied the nlog.config file shows [here](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-2). However, I still see a *ton* of Microsoft.AspNetCore messages. How do I prevent those messages from getting written to the logs? What am I missing?

Answer (score 6):

If you are using the NLog.config from the [wiki-page](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-2#2-create-a-nlogconfig-file):

```
<logger name="Microsoft.*" maxlevel="Info" final="true" />  <!-- Blackhole -->
<logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="ownFile-web" />
```

Then you can change it into this (Changing maxLevel into Error)

```
<logger name="Microsoft.*" maxlevel="Error" final="true" />  <!-- Blackhole -->
<logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="ownFile-web" />
```

You will find your output in the target output `ownFile-web`

See also: https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Configuration-file#rules

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not seem to work. I still see all of the `Microsoft.*` entries.

Comment: @Learner Either you are looking in the wrong log-file, or you didn't deploy the update nlog.config. Try and update the original question with your current NLog.config

Comment: @Learner Maybe also include an example of a Log-message that you feel is unwanted. Please make sure `${logger}` is included in the NLog-layout.

Comment: I think above will only stop writing Microsoft.* logger to log in `ownFile-web` file. But to prevent it from  `allfile`, we need to write the same rule above `allfile` rule as well.

Answer (score 5):

You can't *stop* them, but you can filter them out below a certain log level. For example, you can add something like the following to appsettings.json:

```
"Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Critical"
    }
}
```

That will then only log critical messages for any namespace beginning with `Microsoft.AspNetCore`. Any lower log levels will be effectively ignored.

However, I wouldn't recommend actually doing this, or at least going this extreme. If there's a particular message you're wanting to exclude, target that namespace exactly, and then then set the minimum log level to something more reasonable like `Warning`. Most of the log chatter is `Informational` level, so that will get excluded, then, but you'll still get warnings and higher, in case something is actually wrong.

For more on filtering, see the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#log-filtering).

Answer (score 0):

There may be different causes for this. If you have multiple configuration files (for example `appsettings.json` and `appsettings.Development.json`, then you need to make sure that the rules you set in `appsettings.Development.json` correctly override the rules set in `appsettings.json`. Specifically, rules should be named and ordered and the catch all rule should be ordered to appear last.

**appsettings.json:**

```
  "NLog": {
    "rules": {
      "999": {
        "logger": "*",
        "minLevel": "Debug",
        "writeTo": "console"
      }
    }
  }
```

**appsettings.Development.json:**

```
  "NLog": {
    "rules": {
      "0_Microsoft_AspNetCore": {
        "logger": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.*",
        "maxLevel": "Error",
        "final": true
      },
      "999": {
        "logger": "*",
        "minLevel": "Debug",
        "writeTo": "console"
      }
    }
  }
```

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging/issues/472 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/7995960/474034