# How do I log a custom field in NLog to database?

Tags: c#, nlog

I currently use NLog on a lot of projects. On some, I log to a database.

Here is what I would like to do:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[NLogEntries](
  [Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  [Origin] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
  [LogLevel] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
  [Message] [nvarchar](3600) NOT NULL,
  [CreatedOn] [datetime] NOT NULL,
  [OrderId] [int] NULL --Custom field!
)
```

And NLog.config with this target:

```xml
<target type="Database" name="database" connectionstring="Server=localhost;Database=NLog;Trusted_Connection=True;">
  <commandText>
    INSERT INTO NLogEntries ([Origin], [Message], [LogLevel],[CreatedOn],[OrderId]) VALUES (@Origin,@Message,@LogLevel,@Date, @OrderId);
  </commandText>
  <parameter name="@Date" layout="${date}"/>
  <parameter name="@Origin" layout="${callsite}"/>
  <parameter name="@LogLevel" layout="${level}"/>
  <parameter name="@message" layout="${message}"/>
  <parameter name="@OrderId" layout="${orderId}"/> <!-- custom field! -->
</target>
```

And then log something like this:

```
var logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
var orderId = 123;
logger.Debug("What is going on here", orderId);
```

Is there a good way to do this and keep using NLog? Or do I have to roll my own logger and skip NLog when these are the requirements?

Comment: maybe this can be of some help : http://nlog-forum.1685105.n2.nabble.com/Custom-Parameters-in-Database-Insert-td5557794.html

Comment: What's wrong with string.Format()?

Comment: Rich>> You mean other than querying in the logfile later will be difficult (require splitting etc)? There is a reason why we have relational databases with separate data in separate fields.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

NLog 4.5 introduces [structured logging](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-use-structured-logging), so you can do this:

```
logger.Debug("What is going on here. OrderId={MyOrderId}", orderId);
```

With NLog 4.6.3 it possible to use `WithProperty`:

Call

```cs
int orderId = 123; 
logger.WithProperty("MyOrderId", orderId).Info("This is my message!");
```

Config:

```xml
<target type="Database" name="database" connectionstring="Server=localhost;Database=NLog;Trusted_Connection=True;">
  <commandText>
    INSERT INTO NLogEntries ([Origin], [Message], [LogLevel],[CreatedOn],[OrderId]) VALUES (@Origin,@Message,@LogLevel,@Date, @OrderId);
  </commandText>
  <parameter name="@Date" layout="${date}" dbType="DbType.Date"/>
  <parameter name="@Origin" layout="${callsite}"/>
  <parameter name="@LogLevel" layout="${level}"/>
  <parameter name="@message" layout="${message}"/>
  <parameter name="@OrderId" layout="${event-properties:MyOrderId}" dbType="DbType.Int32"/> <!-- custom field! Note also the DB Type -->
</target>
```

Note, NLog 4.6 has also support for DbType  - See https://nlog-project.org/2019/03/20/nlog-4-6-is-live.html

Comment: I think this is the best solution for newer versions of NLog. +1.

Comment: Perfect! Great answer!

Comment: Working Perfectly! +1

Answer (score 91):

UPDATE 11 Feb 2022: newer versions of NLOG have other  solutions- see [Julian’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12424301/how-do-i-log-a-custom-field-in-nlog-to-database/56719847#56719847).

Rather than using GDC, which is for global static data and fails on concurrent logging, it is better to use [EventProperties-Layout-Renderer](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/EventProperties-Layout-Renderer) that allows to pass custom  properties specific for the event

```
LogEventInfo theEvent = new LogEventInfo(logLevel, "", message);
theEvent.Properties["OrderId"] =orderId;`

log.Log(theEvent);

... and in your NLog.config file: 
${event-context:item=OrderId}  -- obsolete
${event-properties:item=OrderId} -- renders OrderId
```

Comment: Could you add a source stating that GDC and MDC are now obsolete? I tried your solution first, but moved to the marked answer's solution since it's much cleaner - I don't have to define a new variable and manually set the log level and logger name. The only thing I could find about their 'deprecation' is their names have changed from GDC/MDC to what the marked answer uses (GlobalDiagnosticsContext) - http://nlog-project.org/2009/10/19/nlog-2-backwards-compatibility-and-breaking-change-policy.html

Comment: According to https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Layout-Renderers MDC and NDC provided for compatibility with log4net.

Comment: With a custom LogEventInfo instance, you also have to set Timestamp / LoggerName manually which is not as convenient as using GDC.

Comment: `${event-context}` is deprecated now, you should use [`${event-properties}`](https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/EventProperties-Layout-Renderer) instead.

Comment: This sounds more reliable solution then accepted answer

Comment: makes it more complicated. wageoghe's answer is better.

Comment: @Doruk, “Use the Global Diagnostics Context when you want to make certain information available to **every** logger in the current process.” from https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Gdc-Layout-Renderer

Answer (score 37):

Here is one approach using the GlobalContext.

Configuration:

```xml
<target type="Database" name="database" connectionstring="Server=localhost;Database=NLog;Trusted_Connection=True;">
  <commandText>
    INSERT INTO NLogEntries ([Origin], [Message], [LogLevel],[CreatedOn],[OrderId]) VALUES (@Origin,@Message,@LogLevel,@Date, @OrderId);
  </commandText>
  <parameter name="@Date" layout="${date}"/>
  <parameter name="@Origin" layout="${callsite}"/>
  <parameter name="@LogLevel" layout="${level}"/>
  <parameter name="@message" layout="${message}"/>
  <parameter name="@OrderId" layout="${gdc:OrderId}"/> <!-- custom field! -->
</target>
```

Call site:

```
var logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
GlobalDiagnosticsContext.Set("OrderId",123);
logger.Debug("What is going on here"); //If you use the logging configuration above, 123 will be logged to the OrderId column in your database
```

With a little more effort, you could wrap the NLog logger using one of the techniques illustrated [here](https://github.com/jkowalski/NLog/tree/master/examples/ExtendingLoggers).

Or, you could create your own "context" object and write a custom LayoutRenderer to pull the values from it and write them to the log.  Custom LayourRenderers are easy to write.  You can see one example in my first answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4091606/most-useful-nlog-configurations).  There, I show how to write your own LayoutRenderer that appends the current value of  System.Diagnostics.Trace.CorrelationManager.ActivityId to the log message.

Comment: GlobalDiagnosticsContext has some static methods but it is not a dictionary, something changes or?

Comment: You're right, it's GlobalContetxt not GlobalDiagnosticContext and it's  not a dictionary, but it does contain a dictionary which it exposes via the Properties property.

Comment: Ignore that last comment.  I've updated the sample code so that it is correct (or more correct, anyway).

Comment: GlobalDiagnosticsContext.Set() takes 2 string variables as parameters so it GlobalDiagnosticsContext.Set("OrderId","123"); should work

Comment: Hello, I have already write this code in Controller -    MappedDiagnosticsContext.Set("UserName", LoggedUser.Name); and add this in config  -       <parameter name="@UserName" layout="${gdc:UserName}" /> , but this way can not to write username in Db, do you have some recommendation ?

Comment: If you are putting your value in the MappedDiagnosticsContext, then you must use the mdc layout renderer.  You are using gdc.

Comment: Doesn't it cause problem with concurrent writes? - I mean one thread sets the value and another thread overwrites the value which will be then written by the first thread

Comment: See answer below by Michael Freidgeim, this solution fails for concurrent writes.

Comment: Great... Its great help for me. setting in just constructor  and work for all methods

Answer (score 8):

If that's all one needs, as of NLog version 4.3.3 there's an easier way to declare and access custom variables.  **Beware:** ***none of these solutions are thread-safe.***

Add the following to the NLog.config

```xml
<nlog ...
    <!-- optional, add some variables -->  
    ...
    <variable name="myvarone" value="myvalue"/>
    <variable name="myvartwo" value=2/>
     ...
</nlog>
```

Variables can be changed/accessed in the code by:

```
LogManager.Configuration.Variables["myvarone"] = "New Value"
LogManager.Configuration.Variables["myvartwo"] = 2
```

The values can be referenced in NLog.config:

```
"${var:myvarone}"  -- renders "New Value"
"${var:myvartwo}"  -- renders 2
```

As I mentioned above *var* and *LogEventInfo* objects are global. So if multiple instances are defined, changing a value would change the value for all instances. I'm very interested if anyone knows a way to declare per instance custom variables for NLog.

Comment: Awesome solution simplicity wise - gets the job done fast.

Comment: Michael's answer above is thread safe. it's not using a Global LogEventInfo, he's creating a new instance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the MDC code:

```
var logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

MDC.Set("OrderId", 123);
MDC.Set("user", HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
// ... and so on
```

also check this http://weblogs.asp.net/drnetjes/archive/2005/02/16/374780.aspx