# Log with NLog to available drive?

Tags: configuration, nlog

Is it possible to configure NLog to write logs to d:\logs if d: exists, and if d: does not exists then log to c:\logs instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you could do it with a combination of a custom LayoutRenderer and XML configuration.  In XML configuration, you can use LayoutRenderers to specify the filename.  For example:

```
<target name="logfile" xsi:type="File" fileName="${basedir}/${shortdate}.log" />
```

The FileTarget object will create a file based on the values of the `${basedir}` and `${shortdate}` layout renderers.

You could easily write a custom LayoutRenderer, maybe call it "FindAvailableDrive", and configure it like this:

```
<target name="logfile" xsi:type="File" fileName="${FindAvailableDrive}/logs/${shortdate}.log" />
```

The FindAvailableDrive LayoutRender could start with a drive letter, say "C:", and change until it finds a valid drive.  To take a step farther, FindAvailableDrive could take one or more parameters that could help define how to search for the valid drive:

```
<target name="logfile" xsi:type="File" fileName="${FindAvailableDrive:Drives=DC}/logs/${shortdate}.log" />
```

In this case, FindAvailableDrive would check drive D then drive C.

Here is an example (untested) of how you might write such a LayoutRenderer (note that this is based on an existing LayoutRender that I wrote against NLog 1.0, so some of this might not be necessary (or valid) for NLog 2.0):

```
  [LayoutRenderer("FindAvailableDrive")]
  class FindAvailableDriveLayoutRenderer : LayoutRenderer
  {
    private string validDrive;

    [DefaultParameter]
    public string DriveCandidates { get; set; }

    protected override void Append(StringBuilder builder, LogEventInfo logEvent)
    {
      builder.Append(FindValidDrive());
    }

    protected override int GetEstimatedBufferSize(LogEventInfo logEvent)
    {
      return 2;
    }

    private string FindValidDrive()
    {
      if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(validDrive)) return validDrive;

      if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(DriveCandidates))
      {
        if (Directory.Exists("C:"))
          validDrive = "C:";
        else
        if (Directory.Exists("D:"))
          validDrive = "D:";
        //And so on if you want to continue to check for valid drives.
        return validDrive;
      }

      validDrive = DriveCandidates.Select(c => string.Format("{0}:", c).Where(d => Directory.Exists(d)).FirstOrDefault();

      //What to do if no drives exists?

      return validDrive;
    }
  }
```

You can see my answer to another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4091606/most-useful-nlog-configurations/4098047#4098047) for more information about how to write and use a custom LayoutRenderer in NLog.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, but not in xml configuration:
do something like this, wenn your program is loaded:
vb.net code:

```
    Dim mt As NLog.Targets.FileTarget= Nothing
    For Each Target In LogManager.Configuration.AllTargets
        If Target.Name Like "YourTargetNameIntheXML" Then
            mt = DirectCast(Target, NLog.Targets.FileTarget)
        End If
    Next

if isnothing(mt)=false then
        mt.FileName="YourPath"
Check here if the drive exists, if not, change the path to your liking.
End If
```

You may have to reload the configuration:
        Logger.Factory.Configuration.Reload()

Maybe this will not work, than you can try to build a new filetarget in code and add this to nlog.
Here is an example for a Memorytarget:

```
Dim ThisLog As New MemoryTarget

ThisLog.Name = "PPTXLOG"
ThisLog.Layout = "${threadid} | ${time} | ${level:uppercase=true} | ${logger} | ${message} | ${exception}"


Logger.Factory.Configuration.AddTarget("PPTXLOG", ThisLog)
'the Logrule is needed to "route" the logs to your new target

    Dim LogRule As New LoggingRule("*", LogLevel, ThisLog)

    Logger.Factory.Configuration.LoggingRules.Add(LogRule)
    Logger.Factory.Configuration.Reload()
```