# How to NLog to files which names get known on runtime?

Tags: nlog

I need to log the requests to my Web server. Every request should be logged to the file with name format "ClientIP.log", where ClientIP is an IP address of a client from which the request came from. How can I follow this requirement using NLog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using the NLog **AspRequest layout renderer**.

See https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/AspRequest-layout-renderer

To get the remote ip address you would use the `remote_addr` server variable.

```
${asp-request:serverVariable=remote_addr}
```

For example:

```
<target name="..." 
   xsi:type="File" 
   fileName="${basedir}/logs/${asp-request:serverVariable=remote_addr}.log" />
```

It is also possible to **write you own layout renderers** which allow you to define your own context information based on the request. This is explained in detail in this question: [Most useful NLog configurations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4091606/most-useful-nlog-configurations).

Comment: Thank you! But could you please suggest more common decision? (I also need to log requests to files which names depend from the content of the request. Like login/terminal IP)

Comment: This could be done using a custom layout renderer. I was going to write up an example but found an excellent existing Stackoverflow question that goes through this. See updated answer for the link. On that page, search for "custom layout renderer" and you'll find the relevant section.