# Have NLog write to console

Tags: .net, nlog, nlog-configuration

I'm pretty new to NLog. I have a .NET framework console application using NLog. I hope to configure NLog to write the log to console directly. I installed NLog and the NLog.Config [NuGet package](https://packages.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Config/), with the following content in nlog.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd NLog.xsd"
      autoReload="true"
      throwExceptions="false"
      internalLogLevel="Off" internalLogFile="c:\temp\nlog-internal.log">
  <targets>
    <target xsi:type="Console"
            name="String"
            layout="Layout"
            footer="Layout"
            header="Layout"
            encoding="Encoding"
    />
  </targets>
</nlog>
```

Then in C#, the following two lines won't print to the console:

```
var logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
logger.Info("hello");
```

Looked online but didn't find anything so far.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Check out [the official tutorial here](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Tutorial#configure-nlog-targets-for-output).

You need to add output rules:

```xml
<rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="console" />
</rules>
```

Also simplify your console target:

```xml
<target name="console" xsi:type="Console" />
```

Many useful samples are here: [Most useful NLog configurations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4091606/most-useful-nlog-configurations)

Comment: How do you view the console when working in Visual Studio on a Web application.  Which file menue > view > menu window?   I have Output window open in Visual Studio > Show output from Debug, but nothing is logging.  I am logging to a text file which is working fine.  Thank you.

Comment: launch it as console (select in combobox near Start)

Answer (score 12):

You can configure from code as well:

```cs
var config = new NLog.Config.LoggingConfiguration();

// Targets where to log to: Console
var logconsole = new NLog.Targets.ConsoleTarget("logconsole");

// Rules for mapping loggers to targets
config.AddRule(LogLevel.Info, LogLevel.Fatal, logconsole);

// Apply config
NLog.LogManager.Configuration = config;
```

Use:

```cs
var logger = NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
logger.Info("hello");
```